# GIF Support in Q/A

Tags: feature-request, support

Sometimes, specifically with sorting/clustering algorithms, it would be nice to be able to provide a gif to illustrate a point.  Does anyone else think this could be a good feature?

Comment: Normal gif should be supported, you mean animated gif?

Comment: You should be able to use the GIF file format just as you would use any other image format. Either in the toolbar "add image" button or by embedding an `<img>` tag in the post.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks supported to me.

[image]

There may be size restrictions though..

Comment: -1 It makes me dizzy.

Comment: My eyes... they burnnn!! -1, not enough LSD...

Comment: @Lix: Well, since this post has only one upvote (and no downvotes), I can assume that I've successfully hypnotized all visitors into upvoting me even if they intend to downvote. Yay!

Comment: Must... upvote... damn my weak mind and your jedi tricks...

Comment: [ALL GLORY TO THE HYPNOTOAD](http://youtu.be/W84DLa0CLNE)

Comment: Animated GIF size limit is 2MB.

Comment: @Calmarius 2MB per post or per file?

Comment: @MarcDingena The image host doesn't accept animated gifs larger than 2MB. (I haven't checked it in the last 3 years though...)

Comment: I've just tried to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Einfachwirkender_Zylinder_funktionsprinziep.gif in a [Robotics.se] and and it said "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported", but saving it to a local file and uploading it from there worked fine.